# WSL Distribution not found with "wsl -l" in a windows service context

Tags: .net, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I imported a prepared image of ubuntu to a Windows Server 2022 system. Executing "wsl -l" also shows the distribution and using just "wsl" will start the distribution successfully.

Since a WSL distribution is not started by default on system startup, i wrote a little .NET windows service, which is supposed to take care of that. However, even though the windows service is running under the same credentials of the user as in domain user and password, the image has been imported in, it will receive an empty result for "wsl -l" and thus cannot find it to start it.

Is there any priviledges or anything else im missing on why the windows service can't find the installed distribution?

Thanks!